# Extracting the line which contains keyword

Tags: python

Modified the problem, i want to extract the timestamp in col2 whenever col1 has the keyword

keywords=["i can help you with that", "i can surely help you with that", "i can check and help you with that", "i will be more than happy to help you", "let me assist you on this", "to assist you better"]

Given excel data is,

```
    col1                                                                                                                            
1.agent enters(as arrin)
2.
3.I'll be happy to assist you. Give me a moment to review your request.
4.I see that the light in your Modem is Blinking Red. Am I right ?
5.Thank you for the detailed information.
6.Please do not worry.
7.Don't worry johny. I can help you with that.
8.Let me connect this chat to the concern team to help you out with this, 
  Please stay connected.

   col2
1. 2018-10-14 21:16:58
2. 2018-10-14 21:17:00
3. 2018-10-14 21:17:40
4. 2018-10-14 21:18:25
5. 2018-10-14 21:19:39
6. 2018-10-14 21:19:43
7. 2018-10-14 21:21:04
8. 2018-10-14 21:22:00
```

For example one of the keyword is present in 7th row, So the corresponding timestamp in col2 to be extracted

the required the output should be as follows,

[out]: 2018-10-14 21:21:04

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
keywords = [
            "i can help you with that",
            "i can surely help you with that",
            "i can check and help you with that",
            "i will be more than happy to help you",
            "let me assist you on this",
            "to assist you better"
]

for phrase in keywords:
    for row in col1:
        if phrase in row.lower():
            return row
```

So what this is doing is looking at the columns of your excel sheet...

```
          col1
1 Hello and welcome
2 There's a lot to see here
3 Sorry, no can do
4 I can help you with that if you'd like
```

and going through them one by one. If one of those rows contains your keyphrase...

```
>I can help you with that< if you'd like
```

It'll return the whole row. You can print instead of return or whatever else you want to do with the row. The .lower() method is because our keywords are stored in lowercase, they should be compared to a lowercase version of the row. If it matches, we can return the row in its original case. Of course I am assuming you have already managed to import your data in col1 just fine as some sort of list...let me know if you need help there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help

```
import re

keywords=[
    "i can help you with that", 
    "i can surely help you with that", 
    "i can check and help you with that", 
    "i will be more than happy to help you", 
    "let me assist you on this", "to assist you better",
]

file_contents = '' # here is where you get contents from excel file

for line in file_contents:
    for keyword in keywords:
        temp = re.search(r''+ keyword +'', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        if temp:
            print('[out]:',  line)
```